# I have an odd issue with CSS dir in localhost WAMP (Apache)

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp

I've been pulling my hair out over this one.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/icons/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css">
```

the custom.css ref works fine, the one in the icons dir just returns a "The requested URL was not found on this server.", it will work however if:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/icons/style.css">
```

... I drop the icons dir into the CSS dir! So, my local WAMP server install is set to only read CSS files from a dir named CSS?

It's one of those things that seems so random and is sucking so much time and energy from me.

Cheers.

Comment: Please share your folder and file structure

Answer (score 0):

this is mean the dir is incorrect so you need to type the correct one
if the file path points to a file in the icons folder located in the folder one level up from the current folder, then your code should be like this
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../icons/style.css">`
if this solution not working for you try one of those
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem to be a simple dir error. The css/custom.css, it found fine, but the icons/styles.css give a not found error. They are both in the same root dir and use the same / root path, but one gives a not found error while the other doesn't.

Comment: if you add a screen shoot for your folders this will help to see what is wrong.

Comment: OK, I have found the issue... are you ready for this? The creators of WAMP have configured or reserved the 'icons' folder (perhaps filename as well) name causing this odd behaviour. Thanks WAMP!!! I just renamed the folder to icons-css. Now I will throw myself out of the top floor window! ARGHHHHHHHH!!!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is, Apache reserves or configs any folder named 'icons' in some special way... https://electrictoolbox.com/apache-icons-directory/